# Can Ajax access non-controller methods?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I’ve got a class that contains many helping functions, that make easy to do many things for my web app. I have attempted to use Ajax and access this class but it didn’t work. 
Am I trying something impossible? Can Ajax only access controllers?

Comment: the whole point of having controller is to make an entry point for your app. Why don't you create a controller for your utilities functions ?

Comment: Do you use your helper functions after page load or before when razor engine is generating the html?

Comment: Ajax can only access endpoints. Ajax doesn't know about controllers or functions. It sends a request to a URI, and whatever that URI routes to gets executed.

Comment: @TravisActon After page load.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer. Yes, you can make ajax calls into a class outside of controllers via custom routes in the RouteConfig class in the RegisterRoutes method. Setting certain routes (say to your helper functions) to be ignored by the handlers and letting traffic flow through.

The most correct answer for your situation. You shouldn't. Any ease of use of the helper functions would be quickly diminished with the work you would have to do because you are now responsible for handeling all http protocols coming in and going out of your helper classes for communications from client to server and back.

...and your coworkers (or anyone inheriting your code) will end up loathing you for breaking convention without a real need to do so.

Instead of reinventing the wheel just set up a Helper controller your project and make that responsible for fielding http requests back and forth and wrapping your helper functions. It can be a bare bones controller that doesn't return any actionresults and you dont have to build views, it can just be responsible for returning Json with nothing else built out. It won't break convention, you will be able to take advantge of years of knowledge and buildout for http handeling AND your fellow devs won't want to murder you in your sleep because you did something just because you could.

Comment: Great, thank you for the information. I’ll set up a controller as you suggested. Part of me was just curious if it could get done, already knowing that it was probably a bad idea.